Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@1-2--1' is known. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{displaymath}
        \begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
            &[10pt] & \text{SCoS} \ar[dll] \ar[d] \ar[drr] & & \\ 
            \text{CoS} \ar[drr] \ar[rr]\ar[rrddd] & & \text{NS} & & \text{SCS} \ar[dll] \ar[ddl] \ar [ll]\\ 
            & & \text{CS} \ar[dd] & & \\[-3ex]
            & & & \text{PO} \ar[dl] & \\[4ex]
            & & \text{wPO} & & 
        \end{tikzcd} 
    \end{displaymath}
\end{document}

I have this code in article class. Moving to beamer, I have replaced & with \&. but in beamer the command is giving an error mentioned on all cells. I checked many questions here and it says when there is no object pointing on the other end of the arrow this error is shown. But I have put objects on both side of arrows. What am I missing?
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
    \begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
        \& \& \text{SCoS} \ar[dll] \ar[d] \ar[drr] \& \& \\ 
        \text{CoS} \ar[drr] \ar[rr]\ar[rrddd] \& \& \text{NS} \& \& \text{SCS} \ar[dll] \ar[ddl] \ar [ll]\\ 
        \& \& \text{CS} \ar[dd] \& \& \\[-3ex]
        \& \& \& \text{PO} \ar[dl] \& \\[4ex]
        \& \& \text{wPO} \& \& 
    \end{tikzcd} 
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}

Error:
Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@1-2--1' is known. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.

Welcome. // Unfortunately a few lines are missing, so we can copy, compile and improve your code. Please add, what's missing. Thank you

I have edited the question. Is that sufficient for a help?

Why have you replaced & by \& in the beamer example? Revert the replacement and the example works. With the replacement you've just broken the tikzcd syntax.

Yes, your edit was helpful. Thank you

With the replacement of & by \& you've broken the tikzcd syntax. tikzcd is a kind of matrix and needs & as separator not \&, which would just expand to the character “&”. So reverting the replacement:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}% Why?
    \begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
        & & \text{SCoS} \ar[dll] \ar[d] \ar[drr] & & \\ 
        \text{CoS} \ar[drr] \ar[rr]\ar[rrddd] & & \text{NS} & & \text{SCS} \ar[dll] \ar[ddl] \ar [ll]\\ 
        & & \text{CS} \ar[dd] & & \\[-3ex]
        & & & \text{PO} \ar[dl] & \\[4ex]
        & & \text{wPO} & & 
    \end{tikzcd} 
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}

already solves the problem.
To put it into a frame I would suggest to use a fragile one, because tikzcd (or the TikZ matrix used by tikzcd) needs to change the catcode of &:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{displaymath}
    \begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
        & & \text{SCoS} \ar[dll] \ar[d] \ar[drr] & & \\ 
        \text{CoS} \ar[drr] \ar[rr]\ar[rrddd] & & \text{NS} & & \text{SCS} \ar[dll] \ar[ddl] \ar [ll]\\ 
        & & \text{CS} \ar[dd] & & \\[-3ex]
        & & & \text{PO} \ar[dl] & \\[4ex]
        & & \text{wPO} & & 
    \end{tikzcd}
  \end{displaymath}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



thank you.. that works! I read a question on similar error that  ampersand replacement would help. thats why tried it.

needs & as separator not &, which would just be the character “&” Yes, but oftentimes, one uses ampersand replacement = \& to get around catcode problems with the & (which PGF/TikZ makes active inside a matrix to be \pgfmatrixnextcell). Any replacement control sequence works but \& is often chosen.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Usually \& is used to get “&”, because & is a special (here an active) token. Using \& to get the special/active token of & needed for matrix cells does IMHO not make sense and does not work.
